# Override Spring Boot yaml property via environment variable

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, properties-file

Using Spring Boot 2.6.1, If I have an `application.properties` file that looks like:

```
spring.datasource.url="jdbc://blahblah"
```

I can override that value at runtime with an environment variable named `spring.datasource.url` and my application will connect to the database specified in the env var.

However, if I have an equivalent `application.yaml` file, specifying the environment variable that way appears to have no effect.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc://localhost..."
```

However, if I rename my environment variable to `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL`, the override works again. This appears to be consistent across other properties as well (not just the datasource url).

Looking through [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.1/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config) it wasn't obvious why this should be the case, except that yaml configuration seems like it's generally treated a little different than "normal" properties files.

Is this behaviour expected?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [described in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.1/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.environment-variables), you should use the environment variable `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` to set the `spring.datasource.url` property. I am surprised that `spring.datasource.url` worked at all when configured as an environment variable and I would not rely on it continuing to do so.

Comment: I was too, to be honest, but saw it in another project and the thinking was "hey, now the env vars match the property names exactly!" Oh well... upper-case it is :)